# What should I do as apt-get wants to remove grub-efi-amd64-signed

Tags: boot, apt, uefi, grub-efi

I'm on 15.04 and latest upgrade shows grub-efi-amd64-signed as "to be removed" (along with upgrading grub-common, grub-efi-amd64, grub-efi-amd64-bin and grub2-common)

I'm using EFI secure boot, so I think removing grub-efi-amd64-signed might brake my system.

Does anyone have an advice on that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the update yesterday on 14.04, and 15.04, and it went OK.  What I think it does, it removes an older version, and installs a newer one.  Both systems have been rebooted, and they both work fine.

Comment: I went on, ant it works. But there is one chnage: it used to display "booting in insecure mode", and it does not anymore... any idea why?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/587463/how-to-solve-boot-in-insecure-mode-error).  There was a problem, and its now fixed.

Comment: If you see a `booting in insecure mode` message, then you are *not* booting with Secure Boot active. I suggest you re-examine your firmware settings.

Answer (score 0):

This is a a kown issue:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2-signed/+bug/1469995

Afaik it seems related to a dependency problem as updating "grub-efi-amd64" package suggest to remove "grub-efi-amd64-signed" as the last one depends on previous version of the first one.

You should not update now and wait one or two weeks and see if the issue is fixed.

Comment: Temporary workaround to allow upgrading other packages until this bug is fixed: `sudo apt-mark hold grub-efi-amd64 grub-efi-amd64-bin grub-common grub2-common`. And run `sudo apt-mark unhold grub-efi-amd64 grub-efi-amd64-bin grub-common grub2-common` after the bug has been fixed.