# VirtualBox problem: Kernel module is not loaded

Tags: virtualbox, extension

I have installed VirtualBox several times, same error every time ( Also see screenshots below)

```
WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module available for the current kernel (4.4.0-22-generic) or it failed to load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by
           sudo /sbin/rcvboxdrv setup
         You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed. Extension Packs: 0
```

I run sudo /sbin/rcvboxdrv setup and get:

```
Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules ...done.
Removing old VirtualBox pci kernel module ...done.
Removing old VirtualBox netadp kernel module ...done.
Removing old VirtualBox netflt kernel module ...done.
Removing old VirtualBox kernel module ...done.
Recompiling VirtualBox kernel modules
 ...done.
Starting VirtualBox kernel modules ...failed!
  (modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why)
```

When I run dmesg I get a LONG response the beginning of which is in the screenshot provided, the rest of it (and there is a lot) is in the paste(dot)ubuntu link.

I have installed the VBox from Software center as well as 5.0.2 and 5.0.18 64 bit and 5.0.2 32bit. The program itself opens up but I am trying to add the extension pack for USB compatibility, whenever I do it says something along the lines of no application can open this (I have uninstalled it since and am currently trying to figure out the VBox problem first as I believe it is the cause of the extension pack problem.
[terminal errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AYAq.jpg)

http://paste.ubuntu.com/16683032/

Comment: Instead of uploading screenshots, could you copy all the output into gedit, indent by four spaces, and stick it at the end of your question?  That will put the whole output into a readable text block.

Comment: Whole output has a link to it now.

Comment: You should probably consider using http://paste.ubuntu.com for stuff which is unreasonably long, also. Google docs is never a wise idea (people will be reluctant to use).

Comment: @LouieCrisci you should accept an answer if any worked.

Answer (score 25):

First make sure you have these packages installed:

```
$ sudo apt-get install dkms build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

If installing the above does not solve the issue you might have a kernel version greater than `4.4.0-20` which enforces that unsigned kernel modules are not to be allowed to run with `Secure Boot` enabled in BIOS. In this case you can do one of the following:

- Disable `Secure Boot` in your BIOS settings

OR

- Sign the VirtualBox modules as described in this post https://askubuntu.com/a/768310/94759

Comment: Disabling Secure Boot did the trick for me (I didn't really care to have it on). Thanks!

Comment: The secure boot in my case is disable and still have the same problem (Kernel version `4.4.0-177-generic` ). Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 13):

After run this command, my VirtualBox is working:

```
sudo apt install -f
```

Comment: Surprisingly did the job!

Answer (score 8):

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall virtualbox
```

...is what did it for me. Hope this helps!

Comment: This worked for me too.

Answer (score 3):

Just install `linux-headers` and run `vboxconfig` again

```
#> sudo apt-get install dkms build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r`
#> sudo /sbin/vboxconfig
```

Answer (score 2):

This command worked for me

```
sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
```

Next I got following error

```
The VirtualBox VM was created with a user that doesn't match the
current user running Vagrant. VirtualBox requires that the same user
is used to manage the VM that was created. Please re-run Vagrant with
that user. This is not a Vagrant issue.
The UID used to create the VM was: 0
Your UID is: 1000
```

That got solved by running vagrant up command with root access (sudo).

this should fix the issue with VirtualBox Version: 5.1

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything I could find online but nothing worked.

I then realized that I had an unsigned kernel, which may happen if you recently update it. I followed the advice here and the problem was resolved:

https://superuser.com/questions/1438279/how-to-sign-a-kernel-module-ubuntu-18-04