# The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded for kernel 5.0.5

Tags: 18.04

I have installed the kernel 5.0.5-050005-generic because I had boot issues.

Now when I run `vagrant up` I get this message:

> VirtualBox is complaining that the kernel module is not loaded. Please
>   run `VBoxManage --version` or open the VirtualBox GUI to see the error
>   message which should contain instructions on how to fix this error.

What I then did:

```
adam@adam-MS-7A63:~/Programme/homestead$ VBoxManage --version
WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module
         available for the current kernel (5.0.5-050005-generic) or it failed to
         load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by

           sudo /sbin/vboxconfig

         You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
6.0.2r128162
```

Next I tried to recompile as suggested:

```
adam@adam-MS-7A63:~/Programme/homestead$ sudo /sbin/vboxconfig
[sudo] password for adam: 
vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
vboxdrv.sh: failed: Look at /var/log/vbox-setup.log to find out what went wrong.

There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
  /sbin/vboxconfig
as root.
```

I put the content from log file [here at Ubuntu Pastebin](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/YqzhQ3qsFc/) because if I paste it into a codeblock here I excess the allowed body limit.

I also followed the suggestions from https://askubuntu.com/a/779427/247771 to disable secure boot, but it didn't change anything.

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is normal behavior for any new kernel release and existing kernel objects / modules will not work until they are updated and made compatible with the kernel you are running.

Comment: When do I know when virtualbox is compatible with kernel 5 ?

Comment: It's hard to say but based on my personal observations, VirtualBox developers are pretty good at keeping their modules up to date with newly released kernels so it shouldn't take too long. Linux Kernel 5.05 only just got released on March 27 2019 (https://lwn.net/Articles/784134/) and that's about 3 days old from the moment of this post :)

Comment: Update: https://news.softpedia.com/news/virtualbox-6-0-6-released-with-support-for-linux-5-0-and-linux-5-1-kernels-525697.shtml - support for Linux kernel 5.0 series and 5.1.

Answer (score 0):

YOu need to install Virtualbox Version 6.0.4 , if you are installing VirtualBox using Ubuntu repository than it will not work properly with kernel 5.0.5

use Oracle Virtual-box repository and install Virtualbox 6.0.4