# VirtualBox 5.20 on ubuntu 16.04 ERROR

Tags: virtualbox, 16.04

I try install VB 5.20 on 16.04 ubuntu but get some erros and I dont know how to solve it.

```
webmaster@server-hp:/opt$ sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-5.0_5.0.20-106931-Ubuntu-xenial_amd64.deb 
[sudo] password for webmaster: 
Selecting previously unselected package virtualbox-5.0.
(Reading database ... 223301 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack virtualbox-5.0_5.0.20-106931-Ubuntu-xenial_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking virtualbox-5.0 (5.0.20-106931~Ubuntu~xenial) ...
Setting up virtualbox-5.0 (5.0.20-106931~Ubuntu~xenial) ...
addgroup: The group `vboxusers' already exists as a system group. Exiting.
Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules ...done.
Removing old VirtualBox pci kernel module ...done.
Recompiling VirtualBox kernel modules ...done.
Starting VirtualBox kernel modules ...failed!
(modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why)
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu6) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.5-2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160415-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...`
```

like asked in install log:

```
Starting VirtualBox kernel modules ...failed!
(modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why)
```

Here the dmesg output (I will put only errors that apper in red color, if needed more or all info, just ask pls.)

```
[    0.738256] platform MSFT0101:00: failed to claim resource 1
[    0.738260] acpi MSFT0101:00: platform device creation failed: -16
[  154.658154] tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: can't request region for resource [mem 0xfed40040-0xfed4103f]
[  155.103699] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, id=00e0(Receiver ID)
[  155.103701] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0:   device [8086:9d14] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  155.103702] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0:    [ 0] Receiver Error 
[  155.732956] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Unsupported splx structure
```

kernel version

```
Linux server-hp 4.4.0-22-generic #40-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 12 22:03:46 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Any suggestion to fix this error? virtualbox is installed but can`t use it.

Comment: Kernel module and kernel do not match somehow. You need to recompile the kernel module or find the one compiled for your kernel.

Comment: Don't remember and have no Ubuntu. Google how to reinstall vbox modules.

Comment: Can you try this command at terminal and post back the results    sudo modprobe vboxdrv

Comment: $ modprobe vboxdrv
    modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'vboxdrv': Operation not permitted
    $ sudo modprobe vboxdrv 
    modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'vboxdrv': Required key not available

Comment: I found this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/760671/could-not-load-vboxdrv-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-04, can I proceed with that and test it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem.
The solution that worked for me :
access the BIOS when booting and disable 'SECURE BOOT'.
After that, I could install Oracle VM virtual box 5.0 without any problem.