# Unable to run a Virtualbox machine : modprobe vboxdrv failed

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04, tring to use Virtualbox version 5.0_5.0.20

When I try to open a Virtual Machine, Virtualbox warn me that :

```
WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module
         available for the current kernel (4.4.0-22-generic) or it failed to
         load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by

           sudo /sbin/rcvboxdrv setup

         You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
```

So I run the command `sudo /sbin/rcvboxdrv setup` as asked, but I meet the error

```
Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules ...done.
Uninstalling old VirtualBox DKMS kernel modules ...done.
Trying to register the VirtualBox kernel modules using DKMS ...done.
Starting VirtualBox kernel modules ...failed!
  (modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why)
```

And I'm blocked ... I don't know how to fix it to run my VM.. Any Idea ?

Comment: doesn't seems to work (not exactly the same issue)

Comment: As the last command's error suggests, would you share what dmesg says?

Comment: It is actually a duplicate,  but not of the right one, please correct to this question :
http://askubuntu.com/questions/760671/could-not-load-vboxdrv-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-04