# Could not load vboxdrv in Ubuntu 14.04 (and I want to keep secure boot)

Tags: 14.04, drivers, virtualbox, secure-boot

I encounter the exact same problem as here except I'm not able to recover using the proposed solution.

[Could not load 'vboxdrv' after upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04 (and I want to keep secure boot)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760671/could-not-load-vboxdrv-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-04-and-i-want-to-keep-secur/)

I have followed the recommended solution and everything seems fine but still the module could not be loaded.

The key seems correctly loaded:

```
$ sudo mokutil --list-enrolled
[key 1]
[…]
[key 2]
SHA1 Fingerprint: 0f:6f:8e:7a:39:d0:27:33:7d:eb:e0:62:cf:38:b1:af:4c:82:98:c4
Certificate:
[…]
        Issuer: CN=modssign
[…]
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                83:83:25:5B:D6:6E:A0:BB:87:44:A9:8C:EA:47:58:DD:07:B9:A6:C7
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:83:83:25:5B:D6:6E:A0:BB:87:44:A9:8C:EA:47:58:DD:07:B9:A6:C7
[…]
```

And the module is signed with this key:

```
$ sudo modinfo vboxdrv
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-77-generic/misc/vboxdrv.ko
version:        5.1.0 r108711 (0x00260000)
license:        GPL
description:    Oracle VM VirtualBox Support Driver
author:         Oracle Corporation
srcversion:     32F3C607C8086AE6187D18B
depends:        
vermagic:       3.16.0-77-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         modssign
sig_key:        83:83:25:5B:D6:6E:A0:BB:87:44:A9:8C:EA:47:58:DD:07:B9:A6:C7
sig_hashalgo:   sha256
```

But the module still failed to insert:

```
$ sudo modprobe vboxdrv
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'vboxdrv': Required key not available
```

Do you have any idea?
I thought I had correctly follow all the steps (including enrolling the new key at boot, etc)

More technical information:

- Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS freshly updated
- Linux 3.16.0-77-generic
- Virtualbox 5.1.0 r108711 freshly downloaded from the Virtualbox.org website

Thanks in advance for your hints!

**Edit** of 2016-08-23:

I think the issue is due to the fact my certificate is never loaded by the kernel at boot.

The certificate loaded by the kernel is `4a94`:

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep 'Loaded X.509 cert'
[    1.126207] Loaded X.509 cert 'Magrathea: Glacier signing key: 4a94aff5eff7b539906b3f2a9d0cca00dac4cbb0'
```

And all modules are well loaded because they are signed with this specific key (`4a94`):

```
$ sudo modinfo ip_tables | grep sig_key
sig_key:        4A:94:AF:F5:EF:F7:B5:39:90:6B:3F:2A:9D:0C:CA:00:DA:C4:CB:B0
```

But even if my certificate is shown in `mokutil --list-enrolled`, it seems to not be loaded at boot.

How could I add my certificate to the kernel at boot sequence?
Do I have to rebuild a new kernel with my certificate in it?