# VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox

I've installed virtualbox version 5.1.20 and vagrant version 1.9.4 and then when I ran `vagrant up`, I got the following error

```
Command: ["hostonlyif", "create"]

Stderr: 0%...
Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
VBoxManage: error: VBoxNetAdpCtl: Error while adding new interface: VBoxNetAdpCtl: ioctl failed for /dev/vboxnetctl: Inappropriate ioctl for devic
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component HostNetworkInterfaceWrap, interface IHostNetworkInterface
VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleCreate(HandlerArg*)" at line 94 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp
```

I fount this answer here [Could not load 'vboxdrv' after upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04 (and I want to keep secure boot)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760671/could-not-load-vboxdrv-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-04-and-i-want-to-keep-secur/768310#768310) but when I get to the third step `sudo mokutil --import MOK.der`, I got the following error

```
EFI variables are not supported on this system
```

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 8):

I have spent hours and hours, trying various combinations of virtualbox and vagrant, no luck.

Remove virtual box or any old versions of it.

```
sudo apt remove virtualbox virtualbox-5.0 virtualbox-4.*
```

Then try using one of ubuntu repositories to install

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

Worked for me.

Comment: This is weird, but working like charm.

Answer (score 6):

Restarting network manager should help:

```
sudo modprobe vboxnetadp
```

Comment: That indeed helped so thanks. But out of curiosity: what could be the source problem so that this helped? :)

Comment: Also, that works in case you just updated the virtualbox and cannot launch your vm via `vagrant up` because that VBoxManage fails to setup a host-only network as well.

Comment: Boom! Worked for me with vbox 6.1, Ubuntu 18.04.6

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and  the apt remove install answer did not work for my (Ubuntu 16.04) I did get it to work by using 
sudo apt remove virtualbox virtualbox-5.0 virtualbox-4.*
and then installing the 5.1 .deb file from virtualbox  [VirtualBox 5.1 downloads](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads)