# Can't start vboxdrv service

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox

I have installed virtual box 5.2

```
        dpkg -l |grep virtualbox
        virtualbox-5.2  5.2.4-119785~Ubuntu~xenial amd64 Oracle VM VirtualBox
```

I'm using UBUNTU 16.04

But when I boot in secure mode I can't start vboxdrv service I got the following errors after trying to start the service manually:

```
service vboxdrv start
Job for vboxdrv.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status vboxdrv.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

And the results of journalctl -xe are:

```
ene 03 16:36:43 nb-efsandino vboxdrv.sh[3190]: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
ene 03 16:36:59 nb-efsandino vboxdrv.sh[7461]: VirtualBox kernel modules built.
ene 03 16:36:59 nb-efsandino vboxdrv.sh[3179]: vboxdrv.sh: failed: modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why.
ene 03 16:36:59 nb-efsandino vboxdrv.sh[7463]: failed: modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why.
ene 03 16:36:59 nb-efsandino systemd[1]: vboxdrv.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
ene 03 16:36:59 nb-efsandino systemd[1]: Failed to start VirtualBox Linux kernel module.
-- Subject: Unit vboxdrv.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit vboxdrv.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
ene 03 16:36:59 nb-efsandino systemd[1]: vboxdrv.service: Unit entered failed state.
ene 03 16:36:59 nb-efsandino systemd[1]: vboxdrv.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
ene 03 16:36:59 nb-efsandino polkitd(authority=local)[1118]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:3142:3022871 (system bus name :1.1643, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authenticatio
ene 03 16:36:59 nb-efsandino gnome-session[9367]: (vino-server:9541): GLib-CRITICAL **: the GVariant format string '(u)' has a type of '(u)' but the given value has a type of '()'
ene 03 16:36:59 nb-efsandino gnome-session[9367]: (vino-server:9541): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_get: assertion 'valid_format_string (format_string, TRUE, value)' failed
ene 03 16:36:59 nb-efsandino gnome-session[9367]: (vino-server:9541): GLib-CRITICAL **: the GVariant format string '(u)' has a type of '(u)' but the given value has a type of '()'
ene 03 16:36:59 nb-efsandino gnome-session[9367]: (vino-server:9541): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_get: assertion 'valid_format_string (format_string, TRUE, value)' failed
ene 03 16:37:09 nb-efsandino sshd[7466]: Accepted publickey for efsandino from 199.14.10.195 port 50277 ssh2: RSA SHA256:O0FAZNK66J7onAXe1zmqc8ac5uxNHGVbU0ykIoYdvCI
ene 03 16:37:09 nb-efsandino sshd[7466]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user efsandino by (uid=0)
ene 03 16:37:09 nb-efsandino systemd-logind[925]: New session 563 of user efsandino.
-- Subject: A new session 563 has been created for user efsandino
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- Documentation: http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/multiseat
-- 
-- A new session with the ID 563 has been created for the user efsandino.
-- 
-- The leading process of the session is 7466.
ene 03 16:37:09 nb-efsandino systemd[1]: Started Session 563 of user efsandino.
-- Subject: Unit session-563.scope has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit session-563.scope has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
ene 03 16:37:09 nb-efsandino gnome-session[9367]: (vino-server:9541): GLib-CRITICAL **: the GVariant format string '(u)' has a type of '(u)' but the given value has a type of '()'
ene 03 16:37:09 nb-efsandino gnome-session[9367]: (vino-server:9541): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_get: assertion 'valid_format_string (format_string, TRUE, value)' failed
ene 03 16:37:10 nb-efsandino gnome-session[9367]: (vino-server:9541): GLib-CRITICAL **: the GVariant format string '(u)' has a type of '(u)' but the given value has a type of '()'
ene 03 16:37:10 nb-efsandino gnome-session[9367]: (vino-server:9541): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_get: assertion 'valid_format_string (format_string, TRUE, value)' failed
ene 03 16:37:10 nb-efsandino gnome-session[9367]: (vino-server:9541): GLib-CRITICAL **: the GVariant format string '(u)' has a type of '(u)' but the given value has a type of '()'
ene 03 16:37:10 nb-efsandino gnome-session[9367]: (vino-server:9541): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_get: assertion 'valid_format_string (format_string, TRUE, value)' failed
ene 03 16:37:10 nb-efsandino sshd[7492]: Received disconnect from 199.14.10.195 port 50277:11: disconnected by user
ene 03 16:37:10 nb-efsandino sshd[7492]: Disconnected from 199.14.10.195 port 50277
ene 03 16:37:10 nb-efsandino sshd[7466]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user efsandino
ene 03 16:37:10 nb-efsandino gnome-session[9367]: (vino-server:9541): GLib-CRITICAL **: the GVariant format string '(u)' has a type of '(u)' but the given value has a type of '()'
ene 03 16:37:10 nb-efsandino gnome-session[9367]: (vino-server:9541): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_get: assertion 'valid_format_string (format_string, TRUE, value)' failed
ene 03 16:37:10 nb-efsandino gnome-session[9367]: (vino-server:9541): GLib-CRITICAL **: the GVariant format string '(u)' has a type of '(u)' but the given value has a type of '()'
ene 03 16:37:10 nb-efsandino gnome-session[9367]: (vino-server:9541): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_get: assertion 'valid_format_string (format_string, TRUE, value)' failed
ene 03 16:37:10 nb-efsandino systemd-logind[925]: Removed session 563.
-- Subject: Session 563 has been terminated
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- Documentation: http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/multiseat
-- 
-- A session with the ID 563 has been terminated.
ene 03 16:37:10 nb-efsandino gnome-session[9367]: (vino-server:9541): GLib-CRITICAL **: the GVariant format string '(u)' has a type of '(u)' but the given value has a type of '()'
ene 03 16:37:10 nb-efsandino gnome-session[9367]: (vino-server:9541): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_get: assertion 'valid_format_string (format_string, TRUE, value)' failed
```

Any Advice, How to solve this issue ?
Thanks in Advance !

Comment: did you look into `/var/log/dmesg` to see why `modprobe vboxdrv` failed

Comment: You can't run it with secure boot enabled unless you manually sign the modules.   See this question https://askubuntu.com/questions/760671/could-not-load-vboxdrv-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-04-and-i-want-to-keep-secur (which I'm voting to close yours as a duplicate of)  There is good info here: https://stegard.net/2016/10/virtualbox-secure-boot-ubuntu-fail/