# UEFI Secure Boot - unable to sign VirtualBox kernel modules - sign-key does nothing

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, uefi, secure-boot, self-signed

I have a Dell XPS 13 9360, which I'm trying to get VirtualBox running on. I've followed guides to generate a MOK signing key, such as [Could not load 'vboxdrv' after upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04 (and I want to keep secure boot)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760671/could-not-load-vboxdrv-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-04-and-i-want-to-keep-secur) , and then run `/usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/scripts/sign-key` with the stated parameters on `vboxdrv.ko`. `sign-key` exits with code 0, indicating success, with no messages. However, when I examine the 'signed' file with `modinfo`, I only see:

```
modinfo ./vboxdrv.ko 
filename:       ./vboxdrv.ko
version:        5.0.40_Ubuntu r115130 (0x00240000)
license:        GPL
description:    Oracle VM VirtualBox Support Driver
author:         Oracle Corporation
srcversion:     6D8B4900A693FC50489A130
depends:        
name:           vboxdrv
vermagic:       4.13.0-32-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           force_async_tsc:force the asynchronous TSC mode (int)
```

I'm supposed to see `signer`, `sig_key` and `sig_hashalgo`, but I'm not seeing any of this. I've tried running on another machine with the same kernel, and the same result. No errors, but no signature.

The exact command I'm running (as root):
`/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-32-generic/scripts/sign-file sha256 ./MOK.key ./MOK.der ./vboxdrv.ko`

The file size of `vboxdrv.ko` seems to increase by a couple of KB each time I run `sign-key`, so it's doing something, but I cannot tell what. I've also used the optional final argument to `sign-key` to output into a new file (rather than in-place) and the new file also does not have a recognisable signature.

Edit: I should have mentioned, after loading the key into the UEFI key manager and rebooting, I still receive `Required key not available` when trying to load the 'signed' kernel module.

Any ideas how to debug this?

Comment: What happens when you reboot  or try to load the kernel module ? What makes you think you have a problem ?

Comment: @Panther sorry, I should have been clearer. When trying to load the post-signed file, I still receive `Required key not available`. I have loaded the MOK.der key into the UEFI key manager.

Comment: `sudo mokutil --import MOK.der`,like https://askubuntu.com/questions/760671/could-not-load-vboxdrv-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-04-and-i-want-to-keep-secur

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem? I'm facing it with a different module. It's clear that the module is not being signed, so it won't work even after importing the key with mokutil.

Comment: @FranMarzoa afraid not, we wound up using libvirt/KVM instead, sorry