# VBox won’t run please help

Tags: virtualization

When I installed 16.04 I think I remember seeing an option to disable a secure boot for the OS, am I remembering this incorrectly?
I know there is an option in the BIOS but it’s shut off and not making progress running VBox.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

MT -

Comment: Is this virtualbox that won't run as an application or that it just isn't able to launch vms? Beyond vt-x and vt-d there shouldn't be any bios settings that really affect if virtualbox runs correctly, secure boot definitely doesn't relate AFAICT.

Comment: thank you for your quick response, I suppose more information would certainly be helpful...the message I get when trying to start VM is as follows: 

Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver (vboxdrv) is either not loaded or there is a permission problem with /dev/vboxdrv. Please reinstall virtualbox-dkms package and load the kernel module by executing

'modprobe vboxdrv'

as root.

where: suplibOsInit what: 3 VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908) - The support driver is not installed. On linux, open returned ENOENT.

Comment: Looks like you just need to install the kernel driver. I don't remember the installation target specifically, but you should be able to run something like "sudo apt install virtualbox-dkms" and then "sudo modprobe vboxdrv" and then it should work after a reboot.

Comment: I will give it a shot and report back, thank you!

Comment: Here is the error I get after running the last command:
mt@HIVE:~$ sudo modprobe vboxdrv
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'vboxdrv': Required key not available

Comment: That may actually relate somewhat to secure boot. This may have the answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/760671/could-not-load-vboxdrv-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-04-and-i-want-to-keep-secur?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Thank you  sbergeron , i will look into it and let you know.

Comment: It Worked!!
Thank you for the article.  I am new to the forums so navigating, I am noob status. Shutting off Secure Boot was exactly what I was looking for.