# Enroll MOK password doesn't match

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, secure-boot

I'm trying to install Virtualbox on my Ubuntu 18.04 but I encountered some problems because of **Secure Boot**. So I'm following [this tutorial](https://stegard.net/2016/10/virtualbox-secure-boot-ubuntu-fail/) which seems a good solution.

But here is my problem : When I reboot and choose 'Enroll MOK' on the 'blue window', I enter my password, but it always fail...
I tried many times, and everytime I remove **.priv** and **.der** files to re-generate them with `openssl` command, but agains and again :

> "The password doesn't match"

I'm pretty sure that I enter the same password when I generate files with `mokutil` command.

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After several attempts, I finally found a solution... The password cannot be longer than x characters, and I think is **5**, according to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760671/could-not-load-vboxdrv-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-04-and-i-want-to-keep-secur#answer-763245).

I find it strange, but I hope it can help someone !

Comment: Well the prompt for password during the NVidia driver install complains if I
try to use a short password: 
"**The Secure Boot key you've entered is not valid. The password used must be between 8 and 16 characters.**"

Comment: It asks you for the **secure boot** password, this post is about a _MOK_ password. I think you've choose your secure boot password when you installed your OS.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem and it enventually worked by typing the password as if I had a qwerty keyboard in the MOK manager, though it is an azerty one...
(note that I used a short password as suggested, I don't know if this counted as well...)

Comment: I solved my problem using this method as well!

Comment: same. My password was quite long (10 chars)

Comment: When setting the password, it must be with at least 8 characters now. Just don't use symbols (only a-z, A-Z, 0-9; not "ñáü.-/...") and you will be ok (at least if you have a qwerty keyboard).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue on Ubuntu 18.04. It seems like the BIOS keyboard layout is different than the one on my laptop.
I used 10 characters, both numbers and letters, and it accepted once I typed a 'y' for a 'z' and a 'z' for a 'y'.
My keyboard layout is hungarian, like so: qwertzu...

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me in this way:

Use letters (I had nine letters) instead of numbers (like it is indicated in many examples) for the temporal password, when it is created using:

```
sudo mokutil --disable-validation
```

Then:

- Reboot.
- Press any key when the MOK management blue screen is displayed.
- Select "Change Secure Boot state".
- Enter, one at at time, the letter of your pasword at the asked position and hit enter.
- After several letters (not all were tested), answer yes to "disable Secure Boot".
- Start the PC.
- Open a terminal in your Linux environment.
- Load the vboxdrv modules with

  ```
  lsmod | grep vboxdrv
  ```
- The following message is displayed when the modules are correctly loaded

  ```
  vboxdrv               454656  3 vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt,vboxpci
  ```

And that's it!

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is for non-QWERTY keyboard users, that is the huge majority of Linux users. I used a password with the keys that are common between QWERTY and my AZERTY keyboard and it worked fine.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is a question answer site not a discussion forum. If you think you found a bug, please find a bug report. Please do not put comments inside your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when trying to enroll a MOK on a NUC with Kubuntu 20.04 LTS. Inspired by Rémys post I tried various passwords, however in my case it did neither work with five nor four letters. Because I don't know the BIOSs keyboard setup I chose different passwords without x and y.

Finally I used **only numbers** and - hooray - it worked. Hope this helps at least in some   case.

Have fun!