# What causes "PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key"?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 18.04, kernel, uefi

I installed the `nvidia-driver-410` package from the `graphics-drivers` ppa. I could not boot, with the following message repeated a few times:

```
PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
```

It looked like the easiest solution was to disable SecureBoot (which I've done both in UEFI and by using `mokutil --disable-verification`), but the problem persisted. I then reenabled SecureBoot, made a new key, signed all the nvidia modules I could find (nvidia.ko, nvidia-uvm.ko, nvidia-drm.ko, nvidia-modeset.ko, nvidiafb.ko, forcedepth.ko) and enrolled the key according to [this previous question](https://askubuntu.com/a/768310/469822). I still could not boot.

Now, if I look in `journalctl` to inspect my last boot log, I see there are actually way more signature failures than I was being shown. They still exist for the nvidia modules plus a ton of other random modules like USB drivers. I would upload the `journalctl` log but I can't seem to enable networking in the recovery root prompt without causing the system to hang.

I am hitting this problem both with kernel 4.15.0.36 and 4.18.15.

Comment: Got exactly the same issue!

Answer (score 0):

I vaguely understand PRIME (nvidia driver 360ish+) is a new nVidia dual-GPU buffer swapping technique that is closely integrated to the window manager, which means multiple levels of the device have to have some sort of DRM handling, and it can cause untrusted errors. 
As a workaround you could try:

- You can try uncommenting the existing line under `[daemon]` that says `Wayland=false` in `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` (Ubuntu 18.04+)
- if you have dual GPU change BIOS settings from `Switchable` to `UMA` (this will disable your GPU)
- Switching from nVidia drivers to nouveau drivers (I don't recommend)
- Unplugging any USB devices that may be suspect (USB devices may cause this)
- Changing `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line in `/etc/default/grub` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nvidia-drm.modeset=1"` and running `sudo update-grub` after (I believe this enables the DRM for PRIME)

However in my personal experience this is a warning, not a critical error, and your boot issue may be caused by something else. For example, I have this warning, and in certain configurations it blasts this error once a second into the log I see when I hit (Ctrl+Alt+F7), but my computer runs fine. I can boot my laptop with many of this errors/warnings and it doesn't seem to break anything, I can even run games fine.

So even though this error looks bad, you may want to look around for other culprits if you aren't booting. It may be a false alarm.