# modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'vboxdrv': Operation not permitted

Tags: drivers, virtualbox, uefi, secure-boot, modprobe

When I type `sudo modprobe vboxdrv` all it shows is:

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'vboxdrv': Operation not permitted
```

I cant find anything to fix this. This is in Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not load 'vboxdrv' after upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04 (and I want to keep secure boot)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760671/could-not-load-vboxdrv-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-04-and-i-want-to-keep-secur)