# Error while installing virtual box (secure boot on)

Tags: dual-boot, kernel, virtualbox, dpkg

I am getting this error when I am trying to install VirtualBox-6.1. I cannot turn off the secure boot.
I am installing Virtual box for I want to use [Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/homestead)

```
Preparing to unpack virtualbox-6.1_6.1.18-142142_Ubuntu_eoan_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking virtualbox-6.1 (6.1.18-142142~Ubuntu~eoan) over (6.1.18-142142~Ubuntu~eoan) ...
Setting up virtualbox-6.1 (6.1.18-142142~Ubuntu~eoan) ...
addgroup: The group `vboxusers' already exists as a system group. Exiting.
vboxdrv.sh: failed: modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why.

There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
  /sbin/vboxconfig
as root.  If your system is using EFI Secure Boot you may need to sign the
kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before you can load
them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for more information.
Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.4) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.15-1) ...
```

I have tried the solution by [majal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760671/could-not-load-vboxdrv-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-04-and-i-want-to-keep-secur).
I am using ubuntu 20.04.2
Output of `uname -r` is `5.8.0-44-generic`
Please Help.

Comment: If you're using *focal* (20.04), why are you trying to install a package built for *eoan* (19.10).  Problems should be expected?  Why not us the *focal* (20.04) intended package from the repositories?  (`vvirtualbox | 6.1.6-dfsg-1                        | focal/multiverse           | source, amd64
`)

Comment: I have downloaded the package from [Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) for `Ubuntu 19.10 / 20.04`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a Kernel issue,
First install mainline [here](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/08/mainline-install-latest-kernel-ubuntu-linux-mint/)

Then downgrade the kernel to 5.4 by:
installing it
edit `sudo vim /etc/default/grub` as follow

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="**gnulinux-5.4.112-0504112-generic-advanced-06ee5ff5-b952-4d40-858f-869172f710ce**"
```

GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=**10**
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

Update grub `sudo update-grub` then `sudo reboot`
After reboot `sudo apt remove virtualbox-dkms` and then `sudo apt install virtualbox-dkms` to rebuild for the 5.4 kernel

then `sudo modprobe vboxdrv`

done!