# How to sign kernel modules with sign-file?

Tags: kernel, vmware

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 with secure boot and encountered the same [vmware-error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762210/vmware-error-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-04) as described there:

`modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'vmnet': Required key not available`.

One way to circumvent this problem is to disable the secure boot, but I don't want to do that. The other way is to sign the kernel modules *by myself*, following this [very detailed thread](http://gorka.eguileor.com/vbox-vmware-in-secureboot-linux/). There is a tutorial on how to do that [in RHEL](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sect-signing-kernel-modules-for-secure-boot.html) and [in fedora](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/22/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sect-signing-kernel-modules-for-secure-boot.html), but all of these solutions are relying on some script I cannot seem to find:

`sudo /usr/src/kernels/$(uname -r)/scripts/sign-file sha256 ./MOK.priv ./MOK.der $(modinfo -n vmmon)`

Where do I find this `sign-file` script in Ubuntu?

---

Related: https://github.com/bergwolf/rhel6/blob/master/Documentation/module-signing.txt and [sign a module after kernel compilation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74022/sign-a-module-after-kernel-compilation).

Comment: All right, this is a gigantic mess.  Not only seems that [the signature stats for Kernel modules are no longer visible](https://github.com/coreos/bugs/issues/1054), `mokutils` [fails to write new keys](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1263992).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On Ubuntu, that would be `/usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/scripts/sign-file`.

How did I figure that out? I did a search for `sign-file`:

`dpkg -S sign-file`

which told me which package provides this file (currently `linux-headers-4.4.0-22-generic`) and where it was installed, i.e. in `/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-22-generic/scripts/`.

The `uname -r` part is just to keep the command independent from the currently-installed headers-generic package.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did exactly as you suggested, and I believe I managed to sign my files (as no errors triggered at execution). However, when I try to verify that, `modinfo vmmon` does not show the relevant lines regarding digital signature information (such as `signer`, `sig-key`, etc.). I am still trying to figuring this out.

Comment: I had to do this (stated in the link you shared):

To enroll the public key in the MOK (Module owned Key) your UEFI partition must have MokManager.efi installed.

Now we have to manually add the public key to shim’s MOK list:

user@localhost:$ mokutil --import MOK.der
Now you just need to reboot and follow the screen menus that will appear during the UEFI boot to enroll the new key. This is a persisten operation, so you’ll only need to do this once.

Answer (score 6):

From VMware's site, the cause of your problem is likely that:

> *On Linux host with secure mode enabled, it is not allowed to load any unsigned drivers. Due to this, VMware drivers, such as vmmon and vmnet, are not able to be loaded which prevents virtual machine to power on.*

To fix this without turning off secure boot, you can do the following in a terminal:

1. Generate a key pair using the openssl to sign vmmon and vmnet modules:

   > ~$ openssl req -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout MOK.priv -outform DER -out MOK.der -nodes -days 36500 -subj "/CN=VMware/"

   (Replace MOK with the name of the file you want for the key.)
2. Sign the modules using the generated key by running these commands:

   > ~$ sudo /usr/src/linux-headers-`uname -r`/scripts/sign-file sha256 ./MOK.priv ./MOK.der $(modinfo -n vmmon)
   >
   > ~$ sudo /usr/src/linux-headers-`uname -r`/scripts/sign-file sha256 ./MOK.priv ./MOK.der
   >   $ (modinfo -n vmnet)
3. Import the public key to the system's MOK list by running this command:

   > ~$ sudo mokutil --import MOK.der
4. Confirm a password for this MOK enrollment request.
5. Reboot your machine. Follow the instructions to complete the enrollment from the UEFI console.

Cited from this VMWare article: https://kb.vmware.com/kb/2146460

Comment: Hi Eric, thank you for your answer. Hopefully it will help future visitors.