# Installing 3rd party C library. Several errors I've had before whose fixes aren't the solution this time

Tags: command-line, dpkg, compiling, gcc, make

I am attempting to use a third-party C library. Once I'm in the directory for the unpacked file I run `./configure` and get:

```
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating tests/Makefile
config.status: creating tests/atlocal
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating src/Makefile
config.status: creating igraph.pc
config.status: creating igraph_Info.plist
config.status: creating doc/Makefile
config.status: creating include/igraph_version.h
config.status: creating include/igraph_threading.h
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing tests/atconfig commands
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands

igraph successfully configured.
  GraphML format support -- no
  GMP library support    -- no
  GLPK library support   -- yes
  Thread-local storage   -- yes
  Use internal ARPACK    -- yes
  Use internal LAPACK    -- yes
  Use internal BLAS      -- yes
  Use internal F2C       -- yes
  Use internal GLPK      -- yes
  Debug build            -- no
  Profiling              -- no
```

I then run "sudo make" and get:

```
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:2357: recipe for target 'libigraph.la' failed
make[3]: *** [libigraph.la] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/jiggly/Documents/igraph-0.7.1/src'
Makefile:1377: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/jiggly/Documents/igraph-0.7.1/src'
Makefile:480: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/jiggly/Documents/igraph-0.7.1'
Makefile:382: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have also tried `sudo checkinstall` and get:

```
make[2]: *** [libigraph.la] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/jiggly/Documents/igraph-0.7.1/src'
Makefile:7813: recipe for target 'install' failed
make[1]: *** [install] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/jiggly/Documents/igraph-0.7.1/src'
Makefile:480: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
****  Installation failed. Aborting package creation.
Restoring overwritten files from backup...OK
Cleaning up...OK
Bye.
```

I get the same errors when I specify a prefix for `./config`

Comment: I should've mentioned that the only other time I've seen these errors was when I didn't use "sudo" with "make" and "make install". So the fix was obvious, though now I can't see it.

Comment: Turn off the secure boot and try again

Comment: @MohamedSlama What has secure boot got to do with this problem?

Comment: @edwinksl some third party program not working with secure boot.

Comment: @edwinksl http://askubuntu.com/questions/755238/why-disabling-secure-boot-is-enforced-policy-when-installing-3rd-party-modules

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? it seems to build OK on my 14.04 box - albeit I have the GMP and GraphML components

Comment: Don't run `make` as super-user! That will just lead to issues down the road. Anyway we need the full output of `make` to see the error that led to the abortion of the build recipe.

Comment: @MohamedSlama: How did you reach the conclusion that jiggly's question is about kernel modules? The title says “C library” and the rest of the question more or less confirms that. SecureBoot has no impact on its compilation whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

> Makefile:2357: recipe for target 'libigraph.la' failed

- Line 2357 : That's a missing "libxml2-dev" :

  `sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libgmp-dev zlib1g-dev`

---

Note : The igraph library is not a 3party library. Is just one of the ~100,000 pieces of open source code / libraries / applications. (The license is "GNU GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE".)

---

---

Comment: Thanks! This fixes my errors with `make`, though I still get the same installation errors.

Comment: If `make` works, then also `sudo make install` should work. ... I have no issues with the igraph library. ... Which Ubuntu *version* is yours ? 32 or 64bits ? ........ Suggest : Start from scratch in e.g. /home/jiggly/tmp/ with a new unpacked  igraph-0.7.1 . And never never again run make with sudo. -

Comment: Thanks again. My mistake here is silly, but I didn't run `sudo` with the `make install`.