# How do I turn on my WiFi in ubuntu 16.04LTS

Tags: networking

I have an HP desktop and I switched from.windows to Ubuntu and I went to turn on my drivers for my WiFi card (broadcom 802.11 Linux start wireless driver source from bcmwl-kernel-source (proprietary)) and I can not find the WiFi networks in the network manager what do I do? ( I switched from windows 8.1 via a USB stick) my WiFi card is built in can't add any commands due to no internet on PC have to post on my android

Comment: Is it a PCI or USB adapter? Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Is secure boot enabled or disabled? See here http://askubuntu.com/a/797442/246201

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Bios and reset all service to default and save them.
Then restart your system again