# What is Secure Boot? Should I disable it?

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, 16.04, nvidia, secure-boot

I have an Acer with an Nvidia graphics card. I know that to upgrade the drivers I need to disable Secure Boot, but I am unclear about what Secure Boot is and if there are any down sides to disabling it. (Running windows 10 alongside Ubuntu 16.04 on separate partitions)

I've read other posts and people say that it doesn't let them run windows again and this is something that I don't want.

Is it okay for me to disable it for my graphics driver?

Note: Ubuntu works with Secure Boot, this is wholly for the graphics driver.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/755238/why-disabling-secure-boot-is-enforced-policy-when-installing-3rd-party-modules

Comment: Have you tried disabling it once? You can always turn it back on.