# How to launch games by second video card (Dota 2)

Tags: nvidia, games

How can I launch games using a second video card? And why do I have few options in Nvidia X Server Settings?

[image]

Comment: Nvidia drivers are not installed. Most likely it is a Secure Boot issue.

Answer (score 0):

Considering Nvidia X Server Settings screenshot it seems there is a lack of PRIME Profiles item along those two items I see. Once I've met with this situation when I had `Secure Boot` enabled in my BIOS (UEFI). So my advice is try to find `Secure Boot` in your BIOS (UEFI) and disable it. After rebooting you should see PRIME Profiles where you can choose which video card should be active.

Here are some explanations on the subject: [Why disabling “Secure Boot” is enforced policy when installing 3rd party modules](https://askubuntu.com/questions/755238/why-disabling-secure-boot-is-enforced-policy-when-installing-3rd-party-modules)

Comment: Takkat edited the question, but did not ask it

Comment: Zanna, I don't understand your comment. Do you consider my answer inappropriate for some reason?

Comment: Sorry, I was just pointing out that the person you are addressing only edited the question - it's not Takkat's screenshot. As to your answer itself, I am not sure; it seems more like speculation than a tested solution, but I don't have experience with nvidia issues.

Comment: Oh, my fault about Tekkat :)

Comment: Turning `Secure Boot` really helped me. On my Desktop system with NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970 dedicated video card it made me able to see and use about 10 settings panes in the driver instead of 2 as the screenshot shows when `Secure Boot` was enabled. And on my notebook with Intel + NVIDIA GF750M by disabling `Secure Boot` it allowed me to see 3 instead of 2 driver settings panes - the third one is PRIME Profile which is required by the topic starter.

Comment: Here are some explanations on the subject: [Why disabling “Secure Boot” is enforced policy when installing 3rd party modules](http://askubuntu.com/questions/755238/why-disabling-secure-boot-is-enforced-policy-when-installing-3rd-party-modules)

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to add information