# wl module is loaded but not working

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 18.04

I have Broadcom **bcm43142** chipset and I installed the correct **wl** module and the wifi seemed to be working fine but when I rebooted my laptop, wifi was gone.

The output of the `lsmod` command shows that *wl* module is loaded but `sudo modprobe wl` doesn't do anything.

I just don't know how to get it to work again. Once in a few times when I boot up, wifi interface shows up but it only lasts till that session.

Please help me, I've tried everything I could and searched almost all the threads still could not find the solution of my problem.

```
moby-dick@rajat:~$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
cmac                   16384  1
rfcomm                 77824  4
bnep                   20480  2
btusb                  45056  0
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
btintel                16384  1 btusb
bluetooth             548864  33 btrtl,btintel,bnep,btbcm,rfcomm,btusb
ecdh_generic           24576  2 bluetooth
dell_smbios_smm        16384  0
dcdbas                 16384  1 dell_smbios_smm
dell_smm_hwmon         16384  0
uvcvideo               86016  0
rtsx_usb_ms            20480  0
memstick               16384  1 rtsx_usb_ms
intel_rapl             20480  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     49152  1
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
coretemp               16384  0
dell_wmi               16384  0
dell_laptop            20480  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 dell_wmi
kvm_intel             204800  0
kvm                   593920  1 kvm_intel
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
pcbc                   16384  0
aesni_intel           188416  2
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 24576  3 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
intel_cstate           20480  0
intel_rapl_perf        16384  0
input_leds             16384  0
dell_smbios_wmi        16384  0
dell_smbios            16384  4 dell_wmi,dell_laptop,dell_smbios_wmi,dell_smbios_smm
serio_raw              16384  0
snd_hda_codec_realtek   102400  1
dell_wmi_descriptor    16384  2 dell_wmi,dell_smbios_wmi
wmi_bmof               16384  0
snd_hda_codec_generic    73728  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
joydev                 24576  0
snd_hda_intel          40960  8
snd_hda_codec         126976  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core           81920  5 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                98304  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
lpc_ich                24576  0
snd_seq                65536  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
mac_hid                16384  0
dw_dmac                16384  0
dw_dmac_core           24576  1 dw_dmac
snd                    81920  27 snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_seq,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_pcm
mei_me                 40960  0
mei                    90112  1 mei_me
shpchp                 36864  0
soundcore              16384  1 snd
sch_fq_codel           20480  2
wl                   6447104  0
cfg80211              622592  1 wl
parport_pc             36864  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,parport_pc,ppdev
ip_tables              28672  0
x_tables               40960  1 ip_tables
autofs4                40960  2
rtsx_usb_sdmmc         28672  0
rtsx_usb               20480  2 rtsx_usb_sdmmc,rtsx_usb_ms
hid_rmi                20480  0
rmi_core               77824  1 hid_rmi
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  2 uvcvideo,rmi_core
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  2 uvcvideo,rmi_core
videobuf2_core         40960  3 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2,rmi_core
videodev              184320  4 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2,rmi_core
media                  40960  2 uvcvideo,videodev
nouveau              1716224  2
i915                 1617920  23
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
ttm                   106496  1 nouveau
i2c_algo_bit           16384  2 nouveau,i915
drm_kms_helper        167936  2 nouveau,i915
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
r8169                  86016  0
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
psmouse               147456  0
ahci                   36864  3
drm                   401408  19 nouveau,i915,ttm,drm_kms_helper
libahci                32768  1 ahci
mii                    16384  1 r8169
i2c_hid                20480  0
hid                   118784  2 i2c_hid,hid_rmi
wmi                    24576  6 dell_wmi,wmi_bmof,dell_wmi_descriptor,mxm_wmi,nouveau,dell_smbios_wmi
video                  40960  4 dell_wmi,dell_laptop,nouveau,i915
moby-dick@rajat:~$
```

[image]

[image]

```
moby-dick@rajat:~$ rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
moby-dick@rajat:~$ dmesg | grep wl
[    7.585523] wl: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    7.585528] wl: module license 'MIXED/Proprietary' taints kernel.
[    7.588162] wl: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
moby-dick@rajat:~$
```

```
moby-dick@rajat:~$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
moby-dick@rajat:~$
```

I just rebooted my laptop and now the wifi is back but I know it is only for this session. Result of the command when the wifi is working is

```
moby-dick@rajat:~$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0 [1028:0016]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl
```

```
moby-dick@rajat:~$ dmesg | grep 06:00
moby-dick@rajat:~$
```

Comment: What do these commands tell us when the wireless is *NOT* working? `rfkill list all` and also: `dmesg | grep wl`

Comment: I have included them in the question itself.Please help me

Comment: Please add: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Also, is the result the same with or without secure boot in the BIOS?

Comment: lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3 does not do anything and all of these are without secure boot

Comment: Should I turn on the secure boot ?

Comment: No, secure boot should be disabled so that the module wl could be loadedd. Look at https://askubuntu.com/q/755238/350004

Comment: well secure boot was never enabled in my laptop so that can not be a problem.

Comment: It is very mysterious that the card appears in `lspci` sometimes and other times not. When it is *NOT* working, are there any clues here? `dmesg | grep 06:00`? Strange!

Comment: I am sorry for replying this late, i've again edited my question and included the result..please please help me..there is literally no solution on the internet anywhere...and I can not seem to get my wifi drivers working in any of the linux distros and I really do not want to go back to windows..