# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Booting in insecure mode

Tags: boot, 20.04, dell

Laptop: Dell Inspiron 15-3567

I have recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my laptop but it's booting in insecure mode. I tried lot of things but still can't find any solution. Is there any legit way to fix this problem?

Comment: Did you enable secure boot in BIOS?

Comment: Try this but be aware of the cons.. https://askubuntu.com/questions/726052/ubuntu-booting-in-insecure-mode-with-secureboot-enabled/771078#771078