# get back MOK management screen on dual boot install (do not want to disable secure boot)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

I just got a new HP Fury laptop with Windows 10 and I installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS as a dual boot. After installation, I got a blue screen for MOK management but I didn't enroll a key and just continued to boot because I didn't know what the whole MOK key was about. I figured that I would look into it later and enroll a key after I learned what it was.

I learned that in order to have secure boot on, I would need to enroll a key. However, I never got the blue screen back when I restart my computer. I saw on this site, [UEFI/SecureBoot link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot), that the user is presented the enrollment screen what seems to be only on the first time starting up after the Ubuntu installation

> Once the installation is complete and the system is restarted, at
> first boot the user is presented with the MokManager program (part of
> the installed shim loader), as a set of text-mode panels that all the
> user to enroll the generated MOK. The user selects "Enroll MOK", is
> shown a fingerprint of the certificate to enroll, and is prompted to
> confirm the enrollment.

So, I'm not sure if I missed my chance at enrolling from the blue screen. I saw different convos about making keys but I don't understand them at all so I won't even dare try them out because they confuse me.

I'm not sure but I think I might somehow have keys already because I have 3 keys (shim, Code Signing and Microsoft Trust List Signing, Canonical) when I do

`mokutil -l`

and I was able to install NVIDIA drivers when I execute

`sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

`nvidea-smi`

Do I already have keys or do I have to re-install Ubuntu to get back the MOK management screen to enroll a key? I do not want to disable secure boot.

Comment: I had this issue on installing Ubuntu 22.04. I searched and found this page, but after a bit more searching, I found an alternative I liked better. Try this link, if the above doesn't work for you. https://askubuntu.com/questions/726052/ubuntu-booting-in-insecure-mode-with-secureboot-enabled

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into the same problem. It appears you can just go to software and updates and switch back to xorg server and then again switch back to whatever nvidia driver you installed which will start the mokmanager thing again